# How can I confirm my method correctness even if it's passing test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Here I use WebApi2 with Department Controller

```
[Route("api/Employee")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEmp()
{
    var x = objEmp.GetEmployee();
    if (x != null)
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, x);
    else
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Not-Found..");
}
```

When I test the above code in Fiddler, it is working fine. But when I test in UNIT TEST it is showing `Test-Pass` but how can I know where is my data?

```
[TestClass]
public class App1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public  void GetEmpMethod()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //configure web api
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        using (var server = new HttpServer(config))
        {
            var client = new HttpClient(server);

            string url = "http://localhost:3609/api/Employee";

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };

            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to send the request in your unit test. Here's how you could do that and read the response:

```
// act
var result = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// assert
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var actual = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
... assert on the actual employee instance here
```

Also it is worth mentioning that for this to work you might need a custom assemblies resolver if the Web API controller that you are testing is in a separate project from your unit test. Otherwise you will be getting 404 error:

```
public class TestWebApiResolver : IAssembliesResolver
{
    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(EmployeesController).Assembly };
    }
}
```

which you will register in your unit test:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new TestWebApiResolver());
```

Also if the unit testing framework that you are using supports async test methods, that might be the preferred way:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetEmpMethod()
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    //configure web api
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new TestWebApiResolver());
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    using (var server = new HttpServer(config))
    {
        // arrange
        var client = new HttpClient(server);

        string url = "http://test/api/Employee";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };

        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // act
        var result = await client.SendAsync(request);

        // assert
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Employee actual = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>();
        ... assert on the actual employee instance here            
    }
}
```